# Concatenate list of strings in each dictionary value

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

From a Pandas dataframe `df3pa` containing product line items (embedded in MDX query format) and product category codes, I have a dictionary `uni3pa` with product category code `Code` as the dictionary `keys`, and a list of strings `Item` (in MDX format) as the `values`

```
uni3pa = df3pa.groupby('Code')['Item'].apply(list).to_dict()
```

A snippit of `uni3pa`:

```
uni3pa = 
{'3PA SMARTPAY': ['[Item].[Item].[10006543 - Smartpay User Licence]',
'[Item].[Item].[10006544 - SmartPay User Licence per Site]'],
'3PA OTHER': ['[Item].[Item].[10001234 - 3rd Party App User Licence]', 
'[Item].[Item].[10001235 - 3rd Party App User Licence (min 3 per site]',
'[Item].[Item].[10001236 - 3rd Party Apps Single User]']}
```

The final result I am after, is to join all the values in each `key`, using a `'+'` to produce an MDX query that can be used, for example:

```
uni3pa['3PA OTHER'] = '[Item].[Item].[10001234 - 3rd Party App User 
Licence] + [Item].[Item].[10001235 - 3rd Party App User Licence (min 3 per site] + 
[Item].[Item].[10001236 - 3rd Party Apps Single User]'
```

Using [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16971502/joining-valuelist-from-key-value-in-dictionary) (I used many others, but this was the most helpful I could find for this issue) I've been able to create arrays for each product grouping as follows:

```
array = []
for el in [' + '.join(value) for key, value in uni3pa.items()]:
    array.append(el)

In [46]: array[2]
Out[46]: '[Item].[Item].[10001234 - 3rd Party App User Licence] + 
[Item].[Item].[10001235 - 3rd Party App User Licence (min 3 per site] + 
[Item].[Item].[10001236 - 3rd Party Apps Single User]'

#for clarity, array[2] is '3PA OTHER'
```

I've gone for an array here as it was the easiest way I can see to get all the groups into the required format. However there are 100s of groups and it will be a lot easier if I am able to ID them by the name of the group (e.g. `3PA OTHER` as opposed to `array[2]`.

There must be a simpler way to do this within the dictionary so that I could call `uni3pa['3PA OTHER']` and the value is the required format?

Answer (score 1):

This is achieved by altering your list comprehension to a dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> uni3pa = {'3PA SMARTPAY': ['[Item].[Item].[10006543 - Smartpay User Licence]',
'[Item].[Item].[10006544 - SmartPay User Licence per Site]'],
'3PA OTHER': ['[Item].[Item].[10001234 - 3rd Party App User Licence]', 
'[Item].[Item].[10001235 - 3rd Party App User Licence (min 3 per site]',
'[Item].[Item].[10001236 - 3rd Party Apps Single User]']}

>>> {k: ' + '.join(v) for k, v in uni3pa.items()}
    {'3PA SMARTPAY': '[Item].[Item].[10006543 - Smartpay User Licence] + [Item].[Item].[10006544 - SmartPay User Licence per Site]',
     '3PA OTHER': '[Item].[Item].[10001234 - 3rd Party App User Licence] + [Item].[Item].[10001235 - 3rd Party App User Licence (min 3 per site] + [Item].[Item].[10001236 - 3rd Party Apps Single User]'}
```